# Whirlpool washer found loose wire

Tags: wiring, drain, pump, washer

The power supply going to the drain pump has two wires that are *supposed* to go into the connector but one of them is hanging out of the connector. Either, how do I put it back securely or what is it called and where can I buy the wiring harness that goes to the drain pump?

Comment: Model number and picture would help.

Comment: You go to the Whirlpool parts site, plug your model number into their search engine and see what parts it gives you. With the info you've shared, the only advice we can give is to buy a factory replacement and follow their instructions on replacing the bit of wiring harness. If you provide pics, someone might be able to talk you through a repair, but you may still end up having to replace it.